# php array target value by name instead of number

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, object

```
$stat_url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=ECFB8FBC534B61C454899F4D7E99BB71&steamid=76561198129638121';
$stat_json = file_get_contents($stat_url);
$stat_decoded = json_decode($stat_json, true);
```

I have only been able to target the value by number, but the api doesnt always return it in the same order. So I want to be able to target the name (EX: total_kills) and then get the value (85990).

```
print_r($stat_decoded['playerstats']['stats']);



Array (
   [
      0
   ]   => Array (   [
      name
   ]   => total_kills   [
      value
   ]   => 85990 )   [
      1
   ]   => Array (   [
      name
   ]   => total_deaths   [
      value
   ]   => 88675 )   [
      2
   ]   => Array (   [
      name
   ]   => total_time_played   [
      value
   ]   => 7051848 )   [
      3
   ]   => Array (   [
      name
   ]   => total_planted_bombs   [
      value
   ]   => 2131 )   [
      4
   ]   => Array (   [
      name
   ]   => total_defused_bombs   [
      value
   ]   => 1234 )   [
      5
   ]   => Array (   [
      name
   ]   => total_wins   [
      value
   ]   => 47204 )
```

Don't worry about the API key, it will be reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the array to be in a format more convenient to work with, for example, you can set the names to be the keys in the new array, like this:

```
$stat_url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=ECFB8FBC534B61C454899F4D7E99BB71&steamid=76561198129638121';
$stat_json = file_get_contents($stat_url);
$stat_decoded = json_decode($stat_json, true);

$assoc_arr = array_reduce($stat_decoded, function ($result, $item) {
    $result[$item['name']] = $item['value'];
    return $result;
}, []);
```

From here you can get the value by approaching the value in it's key: `$assoc_arr['total_kills']`

Answer (score 0):

Although you have already accepted an answer, a simpler version would be to use `array_column()`...

```
$assoc_arr = array_column($stat_decoded['playerstats']['stats'], "value", "name");
```